# Is there a way to have my searches to individually apply to my tables?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have combined multiple scripts where I can sort tables, filter which is shown, and search through the tables. I am hoping someone could help me with the issue that only the first search box or '2016' data search works. Ideally, I'd like the searches to all be independent of each other, and obviously, for all of them to work.

I did find a loop around with it by giving all tables/inputs/scripts individual names, but this is not ideal moving forward. All of the sorting and filtering works great, so that is not an issue. Also, if possible, I'd like for it to not display all the data, instead just have the buttons at default view.

```js
filterSelection("all")

function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("filterDiv");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
  }
}

function w3AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {
      element.className += " " + arr2[i];
    }
  }
}

function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}

// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
};

function sortTableByColumn(table, column, asc = true) {
  const dirModifier = asc ? 1 : -1;
  const tBody = table.tBodies[0];
  const rows = Array.from(tBody.querySelectorAll("tr"));

  // Sort each row
  const sortedRows = rows.sort((a, b) => {
    const aColText = a.querySelector(`td:nth-child(${ column + 1 })`).textContent.trim();
    const bColText = b.querySelector(`td:nth-child(${ column + 1 })`).textContent.trim();

    return aColText > bColText ? (1 * dirModifier) : (-1 * dirModifier);
  });

  // Remove all existing TRs from the table
  while (tBody.firstChild) {
    tBody.removeChild(tBody.firstChild);
  }

  // Re-add the newly sorted rows
  tBody.append(...sortedRows);

  // Remember how the column is currently sorted
  table.querySelectorAll("th").forEach(th => th.classList.remove("th-sort-asc", "th-sort-desc"));
  table.querySelector(`th:nth-child(${ column + 1})`).classList.toggle("th-sort-asc", asc);
  table.querySelector(`th:nth-child(${ column + 1})`).classList.toggle("th-sort-desc", !asc);
}

document.querySelectorAll(".table-sortable th").forEach(headerCell => {
  headerCell.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const tableElement = headerCell.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
    const headerIndex = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(headerCell.parentElement.children, headerCell);
    const currentIsAscending = headerCell.classList.contains("th-sort-asc");

    sortTableByColumn(tableElement, headerIndex, !currentIsAscending);
  });
});
const myFunction = () => {
  const trs = document.querySelectorAll('.table-sortable tr:not(.header)')
  const filter = document.querySelector('.myInput').value
  const regex = new RegExp(filter, 'i')
  const isFoundInTds = td => regex.test(td.innerHTML)
  const isFound = childrenArr => childrenArr.some(isFoundInTds)
  const setTrStyleDisplay = ({
    style,
    children
  }) => {
    style.display = isFound([
      ...children // <-- All columns
    ]) ? '' : 'none'
  }

  trs.forEach(setTrStyleDisplay)
}
```

```css
.filterDiv {
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2px;
  display: none;
}

.table-sortable {
  width: 100%;
}

.table-sortable th {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 25%;
  color: #f3f3f3;
  padding: .7%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.table-sortable td {
  text-align: center;
  padding: .5%;
}

.table-sortable thead {
  background-color: #0070c0;
}

.table-sortable tbody {
  background-color: rgba(232, 232, 232, 1);
}

.table-sortable tr:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 112, 192, .3);
}

.table-sortable .th-sort-asc::after {
  content: "\2963";
}

.table-sortable .th-sort-desc::after {
  content: "\2965";
}

.table-sortable .th-sort-asc::after,
.table-sortable .th-sort-desc::after {
  margin-left: 5%;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Style the buttons */

.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.btn.active {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}

.myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Filter DIV Elements</h2>

<div id="myBtnContainer">
  <button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('all')">Show all</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('2016')">2016</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('2017')">2017</button>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="filterDiv 2016">
    <input type="text" class="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
    <table class="table-sortable">
      <thead>
        <tr class="header">
          <th>Rank</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Occupation</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Dom</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>Web Developer</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Rebecca</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>Teacher</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>John</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>Civil Engineer</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>Andre</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>Dentist</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="filterDiv 2017">
    <input type="text" class="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
    <table class="table-sortable">
      <thead>
        <tr class="header">
          <th>Rank</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Occupation</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Thomas</td>
          <td>89</td>
          <td>Fireman</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Jack</td>
          <td>54</td>
          <td>Professor</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>Bert</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>Fan Manufacturer</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>Julia</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>Financial Advisor</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Delegate

```
document.querySelector(".container").addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.matches(".myInput")) {
    const parent = tgt.closest(".filterDiv");
    const trs = parent.querySelectorAll('.table-sortable tr:not(.header)')
    const filter = tgt.value;
```